# My code adds the same frame to a vector while it doesn't when the frame is being rotated

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have an extremely strange situation in which the code adds the same frame to a vector while it doesn't when there is a rotation before the addition. Let me show you :

```
    #include <chrono>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <vector>

    /* Write all the images in a certain directory. All the images with the same name present
    in the directory will be overwritten. */
    void CameraThread::writeAllFrames(std::vector<cv::Mat> vectorFrame) {
        std::string path;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vectorFrame.size(); ++i) {
            path = "./Images/image" + std::to_string(i) + ".png";
            imwrite(path, vectorFrame.at(i));
        }
        capturing = 0;
    }

    int main(){

    std::string window_name = "Left Cam";
    cv::VideoCapture* videoCapture = new cv::VideoCapture(0);
    cv::namedWindow(window_name, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL); //create a window for the camera

    std::vector <cv::Mat> capturedFrame; // Vector in which the frames are going to be saved

    int i = 0; // Counts how many images are saved
    bool capturing = 0;
    int amountFramesCaptured = 10; 
    int periodCapture = 250; // ms

    while(1){
        bool bSuccess = videoCapture->read(frame); // It captures the frame.
        /*The next 2 lines take around 25ms. They turn the frame 90° to the left.*/
        cv::transpose(frame, frame);
        cv::flip(frame, frame, 0);
        if (capturing == 0) {
            /* If there is no frame capture, we just display the frames in a window.*/
            imshow(window_name, frame);
            } else if (capturing == 1) { // We capture the frames here.
                capturedFrame.push_back(frame);
                Sleep(periodCapture);
                ++i;
                if (i == amountFramesCaptured) {
                    writeAllFrames(capturedFrame); // Write all frames in a directory.
                    puts("Frames copied in the directory.");
                    capturedFrame.clear(); // Clear the vector in case we recapture an other time.
                    i = 0;
                    capturing = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Here, we capture a frame thanks to `videoCapture->read(frame)`. I wanted to rotate the frame so i used the next two lines. Then I tested the capture of the images and it worked well (I know it because I have a motion object in front of the camera). Lastly, I decided not to rotate the frames after some tests because the rotation takes too much resources (around 25 ms) and I needed to synchronize the capture with some blinking LEDs. So I took off the two lines that permitted the rotation and that's when suddenly, the code decided to add the same frame to the vector.

In conclusion, the writing on the hard drive works well when there is a rotation and it doesn't when there isn't (because of the vector). It confuses me so much, tell me if you see something I don't.

Comment: I assume it is caused by your `while(1)` loop. Before, your loop was executed only once every 25ms, because the rotation blocked the loop. But now, your loop is executed much faster, and the capture happens more often and maybe your videoCapture has no new frame available.

However, I would suggest you provide a complete example, as we can only assume what `videoCapture` is or what `frame` is.

Comment: @Ventu It cannot be the while(1) loop because not only I can see the stream with `imshow(window_name, frame)` and nothing is wrong but there is also the `Sleep(250)` when capturing. I don't know what you mean by a complete example; I cannot add more comments or else I'll be commenting trivialities.

Comment: But you only sleep when `capturing == 1`. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for the minimal example. Your example can not be executed by anyone.

Comment: Alright, I know what you mean now; I didn't expect someone would try to run the code on his machine (since you need a cam and a moving object in front of the cam to make the experience). So I've put everything necessary to run the code in an empty project.

Comment: title sounds like a shallow copy vs. deep copy problem. Make sure your used matrices are not sharing data if not wanted.

Comment: so just use capturedFrame.push_back(frame.clone());

Comment: You are right ! Sorry for the late answer but suddenly my camera didn't work so we had to add an other library. I stumbled against the same actual problem and I used your frame.clone(). It works.